# If I use sparql queries with string literal, it returns nothing

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

I am trying to create SPARQL Queries to RDF dataset, but I can't get a result.

My RDF dataset:

```
<art:painter rdf:about="#Michelangelo">
<art:made rdf:resource="#Deluge"/>
<art:made rdf:resource="#Bacchus"/>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="#sculptor"/>
</art:painter>
```

My Query:

```
SELECT ?artwork WHERE {"Michelangelo" art:made ?artwork}
```

Expected Output

```
artWork
Deluge
Bacchus
```

But the query returns nothing. I think the issue is in the name of string literal of subject. Could you help me, please, I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: using string literals in a query unsurprisingly only works for matching string literals in the data. Your data doesn't contain string literals according to the sample data. `rdf:about="#Michelangelo"` is **not** a string literal, you should read about RDF and URIs and have a look at RDF/XML syntax to understand your data better. I also suggest to use Turtle syntax instead, which is 1) closer to SPARQL syntax and 2) more slightly readable in my opinion

Comment: also for the future, RDF triples can't have literals in subject position

Comment: Thank you @UninformedUser for the help. Unfortunately, I can't use Turtle syntax because it was given as a task. Could I use rdf:about="#Michelangelo" as a subject of triple in my query?

Comment: no... a URI is of course something like `http://example.org/test` or `http://example.org#test`. Please check RDF/XML syntax to understand `rdf:about="#Michelangelo" ` notation - it is XML. Check this: https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/ and have a look at the URIs in the graph and how they are represented in RDF/XML. Also, you can always convert from RDF/XML to Turtle and back. Though not necessary here, you just have to understand RDF/XML

Comment: check how `rdf:about="#Michelangelo" ` makes up a URI in RDF - not that difficult to figure out for you I'm sure